# При деплое смотрит не в тот репозиторий

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, deploy

Такая проблема, при деплое проекта  смотрит не в тот репозиторий `nexus`, хотя локально все собирается, всё подтягивает и смотрит куда надо.
А когда деплой на удаленный `jenkins` выдает такую ошибку -

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project DebtUpdatePush-services:

Could not resolve dependencies for project ft.beatles:DebtUpdatePush-services:jar:1.1.25-RELEAZE:
Failed to collect dependencies at bp-common-libraries:cl.bridge.corezoid-async:jar:1.1.29-RELEASE: 
Failed to read artifact descriptor for bp-common-libraries:cl.bridge.corezoid-async:jar:1.1.29-RELEASE: 
Could not transfer artifact bp-common-libraries:cl.bridge.corezoid:pom:1.1.29-RELEASE from/to nexus-company (http://nexus.ab.loc/repository/maven-company-snaphot/): 
Failed to transfer file: http://nexus.ab.loc/repository/maven-company-snaphot/bp-common-libraries/cl.bridge.corezoid/1.1.29-RELEASE/cl.bridge.corezoid-1.1.29-RELEASE.pom. 

Return code is: 400 , 
ReasonPhrase: Repository version policy: 
SNAPSHOT does not allow version: 1.1.29-RELEASE. -> [Help 1]
```

Почему-то ищет библиотеку тут 
http://nexus.ab.loc/repository/maven-company-snaphot/

А либа находится тут
http://nexus.ab.loc/repository/lib/

В мавене в `repisitory` прописано, где нужно искать.
А репозиторий http://nexus.ab.loc/repository/maven-company-snaphot/ вообще нигде не прописывал.

Вот и не пойму, чего он туда смотрит и как это поправить?

За ранее благодарен